# What can I find in the uncommon and rare item packs?

Tags: mass-effect-3-multiplayer, mass-effect-3

I'm getting destroyed in multiplayer and I'm trying to decide whether or not I should buy some of the cheap 5000 credit packs just so I can hopefully get some new weapons, or if I should save up for one of the rare packs and hope I get something awesome.

However, I have no sense of what kinds of things to expect in the more expensive packs.

> - What types of rare and uncommon items exist?
> - Is there a list somewhere that says which items you can get in the rare and uncommon packs, similar to how a game like Magic: The Gathering has a master list of all the cards in a set?

I need to know what's possible so I can make a better informed decision about how to spend the few credits that I actually manage to scrape together.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are four rarity levels in Mass Effect 3 multiplayer trading card packs.

- Blue - Common.
- Silver - Uncommon
- Gold - Rare
- Black - N7 or "Ultra-Rare"

Recruit Packs and Veteran Packs have the same potential items, though Veteran packs have a better chance at Silver and Gold (like the description says). The only way to get N7 items is from Spectre packs.

Here's the full list of what's what:

***Classes***

**Common:**

- Human Vanguard
- Human Soldier
- Human Infiltrator
- Human Engineer
- Human Adept
- Human Sentinel

**Uncommon:**

- Turian Soldier
- Turian Sentinel
- Asari Vanguard
- Quarian Infiltrator [note: makes Geth weaksauce]
- Drell Adept
- Salarian Engineer

**Rare:**

- Krogan Soldier
- Krogan Sentinel
- Asari Adept
- Drell Vanguard
- Quarian Engineer
- Salarian Infiltrator

Note: Opening a class you already have gives an XP boost and unlocks a new customization option.

***Weapons***

**Common:**

- M3 Predator (Pistol)
- M23 Katana (Shotgun)
- M8 Avenger (Rifle)
- M92 Mantis (Sniper)
- M4 Shuriken (SMG)

**Uncommon:**

- M5 Phalanx (Pistol)
- M9 Tempest (SMG)
- M27 Scimitar (Shotgun)
- M22 Eviscerator (Shotgun)
- M96 Mattock (Rifle)
- M15 Vindicator (Rifle)
- M97 Viper (Sniper)
- M29 Incisor (Sniper)
- M13 Raptor (Sniper?)
- M12 Locust (SMG)
- Phaeston (Rifle)

**Rare:**

- M6 Carnifax (Pistol)
- Arc Pistol (Pistol)
- M25 Hornet (SMG)
- M300 Claymore (Shotgun)
- Disciple (Shotgun)
- Geth Plasma Shotgun (Shotgun)
- Graal Spike Thrower (Shotgun)
- M37 Falcon (Rifle)
- M76 Revenant (Rifle)
- M98 Widow (Sniper)
- Geth Pulse Rifle (Rifle)

**N7 - Ultra-Rare:**

- Scorpion (Pistol)
- M99 Saber (Rifle)
- M77 Paladin (Pistol)
- M11 Wraith (Shotgun)
- Black Widow (Sniper)
- Javelin (Sniper)
- M358 Talon (Pistol)

There is also one exception: The Collector Assault Rifle, which is a GOLD, but comes with the art book, so it isn't like the other weapons and it doesn't appear in any of the packs.

***Other Items***

**Common:**

- Consumables
- Some Weapons Mods

**Uncommon:**

- Some other Weapon mods

**Rare:**

- Respec Kits.
- consumable quantity increase

You can get weapons up to level 10 (X) and mods up to level 5 (V).

Comment: Armor piercing mods are uncommon. I'll go ahead and add that in for you.

Comment: There are also rare items that permanently increase the number of consumables you can bring on each mission. For example, I just got one that allows me to use 3 Cobra Missile Launchers per mission instead of 2.

Comment: I got the Collector Assault Rifle with the Invasion comic bundle from Dark Horse Comics.

Comment: Since this answer doesn't have the newer unlocks I thought I'd link the page I just found that has a lot of information on what's in the resurgence upgrade... http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer/Character_Customization lists what rarity various characters and weapons and so on are...

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995452-mass-effect-3/62111126/692595105):

> The way it works is thus: A veteran pack is guaranteed an uncommon. There are three classes: Common, uncommon, and rare. Each of the items, or at least 3 of them, anyway, (I've never seen more than 3 uncommons in a pack) does a check to see what tier it will be. However, the 5th is and always will be an uncommon . . . except if there are no uncommons left. I'm sure the coding is something like this:
>
> Item 5: Rolls to see if its uncommon or rare
> If uncommon, it checks to see if there are any uncommons left
> If so, it will randomly pick one of the uncommons
> If not, it will give a common
>
> In other words, just because an uncommon is guaranteed doesn't mean you default to rare if you have all the uncommons. A rare is a different class of item entirely. Its because of this fact that if I were still playing the demo, I would be considering opening Recruit packs instead of Veteran, because I unlocked every single uncommon, so I get maybe 1 rare per 15 packs now.
>
> Uncommons are:
> Every gun mod
> Phalanx Pistol
> Predator Pistol
> Maelstrom SMG
> Shuriken SMG
> Avenger Assault Rifle
> Mattock Assault Rifle
> Katana Shotgun
> Scimitar Shotgun
> Mantis Sniper
> Viper Sniper
>
> Once every mod is level V, and every one of these guns is X, you will suddenly stop getting good items in vet packs. Its very dramatic actually; I opened 10 veteran packs at once, got an item on the first three, the third gave me my last gun mod, and proceeded to get NOTHING on the later 7.

This is information that people got by playing the Demo until there were no more items to unlock. I'm not sure if it's exactly like this in the final game (although I think it is).
The author of the post has made [a good guide for another game](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/956858-assassins-creed-ii/faqs/58383), so I don't believe she's making it up

I'll update when I can confirm and delete if I can't.

Comment: I think this answer gets me partway there. I'm not clear on what Rare packs give, though.

Comment: I'm still searching, but haven't found more info. I'll continue trying to dig something up.

Comment: Some characters are uncommon also; I just unlocked an Asari Vanguard from a Spectre pack (It was uncommon, I got a Carnifax as the rare).

Comment: either the smg weight mod isn't in the packs or I'm just EXTREMELY unlucky...

Comment: @yx. I've had the SMG weight mod at least as long as I've been trying SMGs out in multiplayer, so it certainly is there, you unlucky person you :P

Answer (score 2):

I know my strategy has served me well pretty nicely too. Right from the beginning all I did was buy recruit packs until all my base weapons like the Predator and Mantis were level X (10) and all my mods were level V (5). Then I proceeded to buy Veteran packs and found myself getting a lot more rare (gold) items than usual. Right now I have my M98-Widow at level 5 just because of this and my Geth Shotgun at level 10. This way after I unlock everything I can in the Veteran packs and buy my Spectre Packs I will most likely only get the N7 weapons and maybe some Character cards.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually a few Ultra rares that are not listed on the wiki. My firend has managed to pick up two sf them, but he seems to be having really good luck, he has picked up almost every ultra rare.

Two unlisted ultra rares that he has are the Indra Sniper Rifle and the Valkyrie Assault Rifle.

There are two others i found on a weapon stats sheet, the Raider Shotgun and the Argus Assault Rifle, however i believe the Chakram is campaign only.