# What are the odds of getting a character for multiplayer in each of the item packs?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-series

What are the odds of getting a character in each of the multiplayer item packs?

Those packs being; Recruit Pack, Veteran Pack, and Spectre Pack.

Answer (score 1):

The odds change depending on how many weapons you've unlocked and maxed out. Once you max out a weapon, character, or mod, you are no longer able to get them.

You are more *likely* to get characters in the Spectre Pack because there are less weapons as Rare options than there are in the Veteran pack as Uncommon options.

[Here's a full list, which might help.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55154/21320)