# Best way to unlock Krogan in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

If I'm primarily interested in unlocking new weapons and classes, and assuming I've got 60k or so in credits, am I better off buying 12 Recruit packs for 5k each or 3 Veteran Packs or 1 Spectre  pack? I'm sure once I have a lot of races and weapons unlocked for multiplayer, saving for the Spectre packs will be the better idea (unless I need medi-gel/rockets/etc).

However I'm just starting out and I really want (amongst other things) to be able to play a Krogan!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Krogan [are only unlocked as Rare items](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55154/21320), which means that your best bet is opening Spectre Packs (because they guarantee a rare).

It is *possible* to get them in Veteran packs, but tends to be less likely.

I don't think there is good data yet on what the % chance of a rare rolling for Recruit and Veteran packs are, so I guess it comes down to:

"Does this one consider itself fortunate?"

Because you're effectively gambling either way - and especially since there's no guarantee you'll get a character at all (you could also get weapons or a respec kit).

Comment: Got sentinel and friend got soldier krogen from specter pack

Comment: Woo, finally got a Kogren Sentinel from a Spectre pack!

Comment: krogans are SOOOOOO overrated though :/  tired of hauling them up after they rush in and die

Comment: @yx. they are so much fun in bronze. HEADBUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUT