# Are Spectre or Veteran packs more cost effective?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

[I've seen the list of items in the packs.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55154/21097)

What I want to know is that, if I want to build up my inventory of characters, weapons, and upgrades, which of the packs is more cost effective?

I want to get a good mix of useful items, instead of one or two good things or a bunch of useless items.

Comment: Would you be opposed to making this question a bit more general (IE What packs are most cost effective and for what purpose?) since I will be trying to update my spreadsheets for new packs when I can? I think it would be more helpful (and might be easier for people to find for difference with premium packs and such).

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Why the rollback on the title?

Comment: @ktash SEO. This question is currently the first google hit for "specter or veteran pack".

Comment: Except... Spelled correctly by people not using phones that autocorrect their comments.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Ah, got it. Alright, well then let's leave it as is

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Spreadsheet

- [Google Doc Version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsGcWAwDXGJVdG4tdGhzdnpVOUdNbDkzX2tIdFFOR0E) (**Last Updated Apr 8, 2012**)
- [Download (Excel 2007+)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15899201/ME3PackValues.xlsx) (**Last Updated Apr 8, 2012**)

[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

#### Notes

- According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/54340/15643), values do not increase if you already have all of the items in that category, which should mean that these will remain accurate throughout.
- The values in the table are *estimates* and are not actual values. These values are used to predict what is likely better, but without the actual values, this is the best that can be done.
- Ultra-rare items are set to 0 for Veteran Packs based on [the answer provided by rare candy here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55154/15643). I've seen disputes of this, however, so there is a chance that this is not the case. If anyone can show a screenshot of getting an ultra-rare from a veteran pack, that would be helpful.
- Formula used to calculate values is `Cost / Total Percentage` which gives the estimated cost per item level for each pack.

### Buying with Credits

For obtaining uncommon items, buy a Veteran Pack. With my estimates, Premium Veteran packs offer little to no value in terms of uncommon, but some value in terms of rare items. Spectre packs have a much lower value in terms of uncommon items (based on my estimates) but have a significantly higher value for rare items. Premium Spectre packs, by my estimates offer slightly better value for rare items, and significantly better value for ultra-rare items.

### Buying with (MS/Bioware) Points

Again, given my estimates a Veteran Pack and a Premium Veteran Pack offer little to no difference in terms of value. Also, as above, rare value is significantly higher in Spectre packs, but Uncommon value is also significantly lower. Premium Spectre packs are, by my estimates, a better value for both rare (slightly better) and ultra-rare (significantly better) items.

### Summary

Buy Veteran packs to obtain Uncommon items, and Premium Spectre packs to obtain rares and ultra-rares. If a Premium Spectre pack is not available, I would recommend a standard Spectre pack for rare and ultra-rare items.

Comment: Isn't it 2 veteran packs per SPECTRE pack, not 3?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Correct me if I'm wrong (and I'll adjust my numbers) but I believe it is 20k for a Veteran pack and 60k for a Specter Pack.

Comment: Aaaah, I was looking at the Bioware Points (cash) cost, where it's 80/160. That's... an interesting discrepancy.

Comment: True.  A Specter Pack is double the cost of a Veteran pack with Bioware points...someone should tell them that.  Or maybe it's intentional?

Comment: I think that is intentional to make sells easier.

Comment: Can you update this answer to take into account the new Premium Veteran Packs, which are 33k credits/120 points? Description is `Includes 5 random items/characters, with at least 2 Uncommons or better and a higher chance for Rares`.

Comment: @FAE Updated it with a full spreadsheet that includes Premium Veteran Packs. With my model, it is only slightly better than Veteran, but without real values, I could be wrong.

Comment: Where did these numbers come from?

Comment: @kotekzot As I state in the notes section, these are just estimates that I use to illustrate a point. Though I have had some secondary source testing that confirmed my spectre ultra-rare values, none of this information is meant to be accurate to a %, just an estimate based on experience and descriptions, and used to show which packs are likely better.