# How are upgrades in equipment packs distributed?

Tags: mass-effect-3

My brother and I were trying to figure this out today. Maybe someone knows.

In Mass Effect 3 multi-player, when you get equipment packs, is there any algorithm governing what sorts of weapons/weapon upgrades you get? My brother was pretty sure it tends to favor weapons which you use.

I seem to see the opposite though. Weapons which I use, I rarely ever get upgrades for, and weapons I never use, I seem to *constantly* get upgrades for.

Is there any weighting in those packs? Or are they completely random and I'm just ***that*** unlucky?

Comment: Is there an algorithm? Yes, it's a program, ergo there's an algorithm. Does the algorithm discriminate based on your actions? We just don't have the data to make a judgment.

Comment: This [answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55981/21097) has a good breakdown of what the chances are of getting items in the packs.

Comment: Well, true, **something** has to be coded, thus an algorithm, but I mean more of some sort of deliberate algorithm vs. just random assortments (even tho, being a programmer, I know there is no such thing as TRULY random in computers today).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't favor anything, it's random, with (i think) a modifier based what you already achieved: if you still have a lot of uncommon weapons to unlock/level up to X, you'd better stick with the veteran packs. Why?
Because the game will favor the weapons/mods you still didn't complete. This will result in spectre packs dropping uncommon weapons, thus wasting your credits. The strategy i used is this:

- you start leveling a char till level 16-17, when you're ready to do gold missions
- from level 1-16 you buy (vetearan) packs normally, completing your uncommon equipement
- wen you reach level 16 or 17, you can either move to gold and save all the money for when you promote your character, or just move onto another char till level 16 again
- when you promote your char(s) you'll have enough money to buy tons of veteran packs and level up your low-levels with the characters dropped (a neo promoted class will result in gaining up to 10 levels just buying packs, if you're lucky enough)

Do this untill you complete your uncommon armory, then move onto the spectre packs. This will result in fast N7-leveling, a lot of weapons and characters and most of all, no xp-money waste!

PS: i forgot to add that you can track all your equipement progress using [Bioware's social website](http://social.bioware.com). [This](http://social.bioware.com/3949589/&v=bw_games&game=masseffect3_xbox&pid=297851900&display=multiplayer) is exactly my profile and you can see my progress too! It's a useful tool to keep an eye on your drops! Hope my post helped

Comment: Do you have a source on the higher chance of drops if you have already gotten some items? I've heard to the contrary, and I'm wondering if you have a source for it.

Comment: See, the behaviour I see tends to indicate it is weighted towards stuff you don't use - based solely on empirical evidence from my play. For example, I mainly use assault rifles and sniper rifles, and yet most of the upgrades and mods I get all tend to lean towards shotguns and pistols. It's very weird. :-? Yeah, the new social profile thingy is cool though, .. and how I'm tracking my upgrade progress as well. B)

Comment: There is no official documentation or source or whatever about this :) Progressing throu the multiplayer you'll see you'll tend to use less weapons, so virtually all the others are "stuff you don't use" or you never used before! but if you buy veterans you'll most likely get an uncommon weapon you miss. when you reach level 10 of an equip, it doesn't drop anymore, so this is the better strategy to start looking early for rare weapons without too much frustration i think:)