# Does which character you play affect weapons drops in Mass Effect Multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Does anyone know if the character you play a Mass Effect multiplayer round with affect what drops you get in a packs bought in the store between games?

Me and my friends, we have not gotten weapons drops in AGES. My one friend played the Talon mercenary last night for the first time, and suddenly got 4 or 5 weapons upgrades in his packs. Then when he went back to another character, he got none.

Does the character you currently have selected affect weapons and/or other drops in the upgrade packs purchased from the store?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, [the items you get out of the various packs that are available is dependent on the pack you're purchasing](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer/Store). Within each level of pack you will get a specified chance at various items, in the higher packs you also get the opportunity to get Rare and Ultra Rare items. [The drop rates per pack are detailed in this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/55964/52800).

Keep in mind that weapons have a maximum level - once you get them to level 10 you'll stop seeing them appear in the packs!

I have only included the rarity name (ie: common) in the tables below for space purposes. For the rarity of each weapon, [look at this list](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer/Character_Customization#Weapons):

### Assault Rifles

```
Common          Uncommon            Rare                    Ultra Rare
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
M-8 Avenger     M-15 Vindicator     Geth Pulse Rifle        M-99 Saber
                M-96 Mattock        Collector Rifle         Cerberus Harrier
                Phaeston            M-37 Falcon             Particle Rifle
                                    Striker Assault Rifle   N7 Typhoon
                                    M-55 Argus              N7 Valkyrie
                                    Adas Anti-Synthetic     Geth Spitfire
                                                            M-7 Lancer
```

### Heavy Pistols

```
Common          Uncommon            Rare                    Ultra Rare
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
M-3 Predator    M-5 Phalanx         Arc Pistol              M-77 Paladin
                                    M-6 Carnifex            Scorpion
                                    Acolyte                 M-358 Talon
                                    Executioner Pistol      N7 Eagle
                                    M-11 Suppressor
```

### Shotguns

```
Common          Uncommon            Rare                    Ultra Rare
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
M-23 Katana     M-22 Eviscerator    Disciple                M-11 Wraith
                M-27 Scimitar       Geth Plasma Shotgun     N7 Crusader
                                    Graal Spike Thrower     Venom Shotgun
                                    M-300 Claymore
                                    Reegar Carbine
                                    N7 Piranha
                                    AT-12 Raider
```

### Sniper Rifles

```
Common          Uncommon            Rare                    Ultra Rare
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
M-92 Mantis     M-13 Raptor         M-98 Widow              Black Widow
                M-29 Incisor        Kishock Harpoon Gun     Javelin
                M-97 Viper          Krysae Sniper Rifle     M-90 Indra
                                    Collector Sniper Rifle  N7 Valiant
```

### Submachine Guns

```
Common          Uncommon            Rare                    Ultra Rare
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
M-4 Shuriken    M-12 Locust         M-25 Hornet             N7 Hurricane
                M-9 Tempest         Geth Plasma SMG         Collector SMG
                                                            Blood Pack Punisher
```

---

#### Useful reading

- [How are upgrades in equipment packs distributed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/65455/52800)
- [Are Spectre or Veteran packs more cost effective?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/55964/52800)

Comment: Yeah, all my weapons are maxed out except for about a dozen ultra rares... so I am just desperately waiting for those! lol ... can't seem to figure any way to get them... tried Aresenals, usually go with Premium SPECTREs... bubkas!  :(

Comment: pretty much premium spectre packs all the way!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what character you are playing as has any affect on what drops you get from your crates. My experience with the PS3/360/PC versions of the game is that the best ways to get more weapon drops is to buy the lower level crates until you have all the Un/Commons and then start buying the Arsenal Packs to maximize your chances for weapon drops. Sounds like you're just getting slammed by the random drop chances, which happens to me frequently.

Comment: Yeah... we've been trying to figure out how to get more, cuz we have everything but the Ultra Rares all maxed out already! So when he suddenly got a bunch of weapons with a new character last night, we got desperately hopeful! LOL