# How can I tell which weapon is rare in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 3 multiplayer store, you get to purchase various packs at different prices. For instance, the Spectre Pack gives you at least one Rare item out of the 5 random items that you receive.

My question is, how can I tell which weapon is rare, which is uncommon and which is common? Essentially if I want a specific weapon, knowing its rarity allows me to decide which pack to stick to buying.

Comment: easiest way is to look on [this list](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54333/what-can-i-find-in-the-uncommon-and-rare-item-packs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Class • Common (blue) • Uncommon (silver) • Rare (gold)**
Adept • Human Male/Female • Drell • Asari/Asari Justicar

Engineer • Human Male/Female • Salarian • Quarian/Geth

Infiltrator • Human Male/Female • Quarian • Salarian/Geth

Sentinel • Human Male/Female • Turian • Krogan/Batarian

Soldier • Human Male/Female • Turian • Krogan/Batarian

Vanguard • Human Male/Female • Asari • Drell/Krogan Battlemaster

**You can find both lists [here](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer).**

**Weapon • Common (blue) • Uncommon (silver) • Rare (gold) • Ultra-Rare (black)**

- Assault Rifles

  - (Blue) M-8 Avenger
  - (Silver) M-15 Vindicator/M-96 Mattock/Phaeston
  - (Gold) Geth Pulse Rifle/Collector Assault Rifle/M-37 Falcon/M-76 Revenant/Striker Assault Rifle
  - (Black) M-99 Saber
- Heavy Pistols

  - (Blue) M-3 Predator
  - (Silver) M-5 Phalanx
  - (Gold) Arc Pistol/M-6 Carnifex
  - (Black) M-77 Paladin/Scorpion/M-358 Talon/N7 Eagle
- Shotguns

  - (Blue) M-23 Katana
  - (Silver) M-22 Eviscerator/M-27 Scimitar
  - (Gold) Disciple/Geth Plasma Shotgun/Graal Spike Thrower/M-300 Claymore
  - (Black) M-11 Wraith/N7 Crusader
- Sniper Rifles

  - (Blue) M-92 Mantis
  - (Silver) M-13 Raptor/M-29 Incisor/M-97 Viper
  - (Gold) M-98 Widow/Kishock Harpoon Gun
  - (Black) Black Widow/Javelin/N7 Valiant
- Submachine Guns

  - (Blue) M-4 Shuriken
  - (Silver) M-12 Locust/M-9 Tempest
  - (Gold) M-25 Hornet/Geth Plasma SMG3
  - (Black) N7 Hurricane

Comment: Dude.. that is fantastic!

Comment: @JamesJiao I left out the N7 weapons though, because the only way to get them is from weekend events where you are guaranteed one of them in the crate.

Comment: I believe that you left off the ultra rare geth spitfire assault rifle.

Answer (score 4):

When you open a pack, the item cards themselves show their rarity based on the color of the edge of the card.

[image]

The Drell Vanguard is a rare, and so is gold.

Silver means uncommon, and Black with an N7 logo means "Ultra Rare".

Comment: I think my answer is more geared towards the unknown. How would one know whether an item is a rare if he's never seen it before?

Comment: @JamesJiao How would you see an item without seeing its item card?

Comment: No I mean, if I want the Mattock, but I haven't unlocked it yet. So I have no idea whether it's rare or uncommon beforehand. If it's rare, I'd buy the Spectre Pack; if it's uncommon, then I'd buy the Veteran Pack, which is 3x cheaper and gives me a guaranteed uncommon every time. Essentially I am looking for the fastest route to get what I want in terms of which pack to buy in the store.

Comment: Btw, you must've hit the jackpot to get two Drell Vanguard cards in one pack!!