# Strategies for obtaining weapon/character/equipment upgrades in Mass Effect 3 Multiplayer

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Spectre or Veteran packs more cost effective?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55964/are-spectre-or-veteran-packs-more-cost-effective)

So in the Mass Effect 3 multiplayer you start with a pretty limited selection of character classes, equipment and weapons.  By playing games you earn credits which you can then spend on equipment packs in the store which contain a random selection of consumables, weapons, characters and equipment with various likelihoods of obtaining each.

Different packs contain different numbers of items and guarantee different numbers of uncommon/rare items.  So what I'm wondering is whether the best way to obtain new items is to buy lots of the cheaper packs or to save up and buy the higher tier packs i.e. favor quality over quantity.  Btw [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62270/how-can-i-tell-which-weapon-is-rare-in-mass-effect-3) has a good discussion on rarity of items but was more asking about obtaining a specific item.  I'm less interested in a specific item more in how best to unlock as many items as possible.

Does anyone who's been playing the multiplayer for some time have a good strategy for this or is it mostly luck whether your choice of purchase gives you something you actually want?

Comment: Just discovered http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55964/are-spectre-or-veteran-packs-more-cost-effective which is a near duplicate question and pretty much answers my question - moderators feel free to mark as duplicate if you wish